# Missing Target Local Server in Job

Tags: sql-server-2016, sql-server-agent

SQL Server 2016 Enterprise, CU15 + GDR.

Client recently started using [OPCON](https://smatechnologies.com/opcon-automation) in production and I noticed that when OPCON creates jobs, it doesn't add the Local Server as the target. This prevents the job from executing.

[image]

Is there anyway to determine if a specific job doesn't have any target server defined as is the case above?

Thanks,
Craig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selecting all jobs that have an enabled schedule but no next run date.

```
SELECT
    sj.name AS job_name,
    sjs.next_run_date,
    syss.enabled AS schedule_enabled
  FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs sj
  INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules sjs ON sj.job_id = sjs.job_id 
  INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysschedules syss ON sjs.schedule_id = syss.schedule_id 
  WHERE 
  1=1
 AND  sjs.next_run_date = 0
 AND syss.enabled = 1
```